# Youtube Error Code: -501

Tags: android, youtube

I am using Redmi Note 3 mobile

It is provided with Youtube as part of system App and cannot be uninstalled

Google Play Store keep sending notification about available update for Youtube, but when I opt for update, I get the following message:-

```
Can't install app
"YouTube" can't be installed. 
Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting.
(Error code: -501).
```

Clicking get help troubleshooting provided no solution.

I have taken the screen shot of error message and sent it to Redmi Mobile Service Center, who suggested factory reset for resolving the problem.

Is there any other solution for this error than factory reset?